# Does slowAES allow/support zero padding?

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes

I'm trying to perform AES encryption in CBC mode with zero padding. Does anyone know if aesSlow supports zero padding? Based on my reading of the code it doesn't and if that's the case; can anyone tell me why?

I'm using a 3rd party API which requires this encryption method.

jsfiddle.net/NMATS/2 is my current POC. I'll bemoving it to node once it's debugged. Also the inputs are similar but different for security.

Cheers,
Denis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are correct.  It appears to use PKCS7.  Your options then are:

1. Pad it with 0's yourself and discard the last block of ciphertext
2. Edit the code and make the padding function do zero-padding (beware of license restrictions - I didn't look at the license)

As to why, I'd guess they just haven't had a need to do it or the time to implement it yet.

If you go with option 1, PKCS7 adds a full block of `0x10` bytes if your plaintext is already the multiple of a block size.  Therefore, you can just pad your plaintext with `0x00` bytes to make it a multiple of a block size and encrypt it.  Then you would drop the last 128-bits of the ciphertext (which is just 16 bytes of 0xFF encrypted).  You will end up with a compatible result.

If you go with option 2, I'm not sure which implementation you are using, but I think they're all simple enough.

Here is the padding function for the Javascript implementation:

```
    padBytesIn: function(data) {
            var len = data.length;
            var padByte = 16 - (len % 16);
            for (var i = 0; i < padByte; i++) {
                    data.push(padByte);
            }
    },
```

Here is what you would change it to:

```
    padBytesIn: function(data) {
            var len = data.length;
            if( len % 16 > 0 ){
                var padLen = 16 - (len % 16);
                for (var i = 0; i < padLen; i++) {
                        data.push(0);
                }
            }
    },
```

Comment: correction: you add 16 bytes of value 0x10, otherwise you are correct. (or 15 bytes of value 0xF, ... up to one byte of 0x1; if you do not pad to 0 mod 16 bytes with 0's)

Comment: Sry Henno, you lost me there? What would be the code change? I've got my sample attempt @ http://jsfiddle.net/NMATS/1/ This will be moved to node later, also the key, iv and member access are all similar but but different for security.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma can you please elaborate?  I'm pretty sure everything above is correct.  I just had a look over it again.  Are you talking about option 1 or option 2?  @Denis Hoctor - looks like it's working properly for you, yes?

Comment: @Luke It seems correct but the service I'm using it against is returning an error. http://jsfiddle.net/NMATS/2 is my use case but I obviously can't share my actual keys. Think I'll add this as an issue to slowAES on google code. Thanks

Comment: @Denis, @Luke I was just correcting the statement that you would add blocks of 0xFF; the solution as stated works if you pad to multiples of 16 yourself. The 0xFF should be 0x10 (the number of padded bytes)

Comment: @Henno Brandsma you are correct!  Thanks for pointing that out.  I fixed it in the answer above.